Why is the cyclic group defined in terms of integer powers?
In "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics" Peter Szekeres (p. 29) defines cyclic groups as follows:

If a group $G$ has an element $a$ such that its powers $\{a, a^2, a^3, \ldots\}$ run through all of its elements, then $G$ is said to be a cyclic group and $a$ is called a generator of the group.

Wikipedia defines it similarly.
Previously (p. 27), he had defined

A group is a set $G$ together with a law of composition that assigns to any pair of elements $g, h \in G$ an element $g h \in G$, called their product satisfying the following three conditions:....

My understanding here is that product is simply a stand-in term for the result of applying whatever the binary operation is (e.g., multiplication, addition, etc.) so product does not necessarily imply multiplication.
The use of the term "powers" above throws me off a bit, because it sounds like exponentiation, which to me (at least in the context of integer powers) means repeated multiplication. Does powers instead simply mean repeated application of the binary operation? Is this the general convention in when dealing with groups? That is, when discussing groups in general (where the binary operation is not specified), do we conventionally use terms traditionally reserved for multiplication (e.g., product, powers, exponentiation) and it is understood that these terms and notation are replaced with the appropriate terms and notation when not referring to multiplication?

Unsurprisingly, Szekeres' definition is wrong. The right definition would allow 0th and negative powers as well. A better definition would be that $G$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $a$.

@MoisheKohan the author did say integer powers, so allowing 0 and negatives.

@Malady: Actually, he did not say "integer", I just checked the book.

@MoisheKohan You say "unsurprisingly". Do you find Szekeres to make frequent errors such as this?

@MattHusz: Physics textbooks in general when they discuss math.

As written, I don't find the quotation to be wrong but rather incomplete.  It's not a proper definition.

@MoisheKohan I hate to hear that but it corroborates my experience. I've set aside a number of other physics resources over frustrations with careless treatment of math (eg Tong's lecture notes). I've found a number of errors in Szekeres too, but it at least attempts to be rigorous and I can usually spot the errors (I think). I wish I could learn mathematical physics from a text without these problems. Unfortunately, studying proper, discipline-specific mathematical texts to learn mathematical physics is probably too much of a time commitment for me, at least at the moment.

I understand. However, Szekeres' book is still better than most.

That's a relief - "better than most" is the impression I was operating under and is hopefully good enough for a first pass. I have actually been compiling an errata for the text, though admittedly I wouldn't consider myself qualified for that without someone else validating it. I reached out to Szekeres too, who expressed some slight interest in it, though he's getting up in years and said he wasn't up to such a task himself. I thought about providing it to the publisher and hosting it myself (with my contact details for corrections) if the publisher won't do anything with it. (1/2)

But, of course, if there's a better alternative, I'm all ears! It seems like this could be a great text if the errors were fixed - I haven't found other physics texts that try to be rigorous about math in the way that this text is. (2/2)

Continuing on, he seems to run with this definition: "If $G$ is a finite cyclic group and $a$ is a generator, then there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $a^m=e$." I expect $e$ represents the identity element. Is this all just wrong? For example, it would seem that $a^0$ might produce the identity element in certain cases.

There's nothing wrong at all with that statement you've quoted.  Yes, $e$ represents the identity element.  In fact, $a^0$ represents the identity element in every group, but this doesn't prevent $a^m=e$ for some positive $m$ as well.  Nothing here says that the exponent is unique and in fact it cannot be unique when the group is finite.  (if you are interpreting it as saying $a^m=e$ only for positive $m$, then that would be false, but that's not what is being said)

An earlier thread discussing a similar theme. Another.

In case of finite cyclic groups the definition is not wrong. Perhaps there is some context in the book from which it is clear that only finite groups are discussed?

@Vincent: No, in this "definition" author does not restrict to finite groups, I checked the book. After giving a faulty definition author says "If $G$ is a finite cyclic group..."

Yes, in group theory we will use the terminology of exponentiation to represent repeatedly applying the group operation by an element, or its inverse:
$a^n = a \cdot a \cdots a$ ($n$ times), $a^{-n} = a^{-1} \cdot a^{-1} \cdots a^{-1}$ ($n$ times), $a^0 = 1 = e = \text{identity}$ where $\cdot$ is the group operation. We do this even when the operation is not a multiplication at all.

Worth noting that we do that because we most commonly refer to the group operation as multiplication.

Also worth noting that when we write the operation additively it's common to use $n a$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ is an element of the group for the same thing, i.e $na = a+a+\cdots+a$ $n$ times for $n \ge 1$ and $0a = 0$ and $na = (-n)(-a)$ for $n < 0$.

@jgon And also worth noting and even more confusing is the fact that even
when the operation is written additively and its repeated application
is called multiplication and written as $na$, the
inverse operation (for finding $n$) may be called (discrete) logarithm.

Yes, the exponentiation refers to repeatedly applying the group operation.
Note,  for a finite cyclic group it turns out to be equivalent to write all positive powers or all integer powers.   The proof of this little fact just use the division algorithm. Or you could just use positive powers and write "the group generated by", for any cyclic group.

The default in groups generally is to represent the binary operator with juxtaposition (that's where you just write the elements together with no operator between them, e.g. $xy$ rather than $x\cdot y$) and to treat the operator like multiplication. Generally, if addition is used to represent the operator, it's because it's known that the operator is abelian, and/or the elements naturally form a ring or field with another operation. For instance, if you're considering the integers numbers as a group, you'd likely represent the operator as addition, as it would be weird to say $5*2=7$.

Natural numbers are not a group. A monoid at best.

@user3840170 Whoops. Natural numbers -> integers
